# Negative Binomial vs. Discrete Survival

Tags: survival, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution, discrete-time

I am trying to model a discrete duration variable (number of weeks) and I am not sure which model to use.

Many would argue that durations are modeled using survival models. However, in J. Hilbes book “Negative Binomial Regressions”, he models the length of a hospital stay with a (zero-truncated) negative binomial model.

Why choose the negative binomial? Are there particular advantages, I am missing?

A linked question was asked here, where answers indicated to use survival model for a length of stay, although the asker also used negative binomial . [Negative Binomial Regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130687/negative-binomial-regression)

Thank you in advance for your answer.